# combine two sentence into one sentence

Tags: american-english

I want to combine two sentence into one sentence.
But I'm not sure what whether correct or not.

1. I have been honeymoon trip to Hongkong.
2. It was my last trip.

1+2: I have been honeymoon trip (that) was my last trip to HongKong.

Is this correct? Or is there any other options?
How about to use 'was' make sentence at #1 instead 'have pp'?
I'm not sure what is correct using tense?

How about this for else option, instead #1. 
1-1 I did honeymoon trip to Hongkong.
2-1 It was my last trip.
3-1 I did honeymoon trip (that) was my last trip to hongkong.

Comment: "I went honeymoon trip" is not grammatical. You can go _on a_ trip, or _take a_ trip. You certainly need an article :)

Comment: Where do you see 'went' in my sentence?

Comment: Sure, there was no went. Very sharp. But "I have been honeymoontrip" is as bad, and whether you say "went", "have been", "did", "invented" or "could possibly have executed" does not change the main point of my remark: your sentence is ungrammatical because of the way you use "honeymoon trip". But if you prefer to joke about the verb I chose in my example sentence when trying to point out a mistake in order to help you, be my guest ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentence 1 is not correct.  It needs "on", or other wording.

I have been on my honeymoon trip to Hong Kong.
I was on my honeymoon trip to Honk Kong.
I went to Hong Kong on my honeymoon.

Sentence 2 uses "last".  Do you mean "latest,most recent", or "last, I will never go again."

Putting the two main sentences together

I have been on my honeymoon which was my latest trip to Hong Kong.

I was on my honeymoon trip to Hong Kong ; it was my last trip.  (Fancy semi-colon)
On my last trip to Hong Kong I went on my honeymoon.
My last trip to Hong Kong was my honeymoon.

Comment: Thanks steve, if you can, Would you please let me know why  'on' is needed to the sentence as grammatically? Then should I have to use always 'on' in every sentence with have been structure sentence?

Comment: Also should I use 'my' in your answer in sentence 1?

Comment: @user1917217: no, you have to use _on_ with _trip_. You go _on a trip_, you do not go _a trip_. The verb or the verb tense is less important. For _my_: you need either an article or some other qualifier (_my_ or _our_): you go on _a_ trip, you do not go on trip.

Comment: @oerkelens : Let me ask you one more above relative above question. Which one is more prefer sentence. 1. I was join this project since 4 years ago. 2. I have joined this project since 4 years ago. 3. I joined this project since 4 years ago.

Comment: Also I want to ask @Wichita Steve about above question too.

Comment: None of the 3 "join project" sentences are correct.
I joined this project 4 years ago.
I have been on this project now for 4 years.
It has been 4 years since I joined this project.
I have been working on this project since 4 years ago.

Comment: @user1917217: none of them are correct. But maybe that deserves it's own question.

Comment: @oerkelens :  I have confused what sentence is correct? Did you mean thatSteve's answers are all wrong?

Comment: @Wichita Steve : Please make sure about which are correct sentence ? As beginner, your answer have hardly recognized.

Comment: @user1917217: _none_ of the three "join project" sentences that _you_ asked about is correct. Wichita Steve's sentences _are_ correct. But it is better to ask a new question about that.

Answer (score 0):

You could say: "I went to honeymoon trip in Hong Kong. It was my last trip."

Or

"I did my honeymoon trip in Hong Kong. It was my last trip. "

Breaking these sentences with a 'period' looks much better.

Or much better is:

"In my last trip I went honeymooning in Hong Kong"

Comment: "To honeymoon trip" makes me think that "Honeymoon Trip" is a place in Hong Kong. I think _I went on a honeymoon trip_ is better.