# The usage of 'have been on'

Tags: american-english

As I know, have been is present perfect sentence. But when I want to tell which of somewhere experience of mine, I know, I have to use 'to' at this present perfect sentence.
but someone is use 'on' but I don't know what is this for usage.
For example, I have been on this project 4 years ago.
As I know, the on is also used in trip as verb.

so please let me know when do I use 'on' in present perfect sentence.
If you don't mind , let me know what else options?

Comment: This is a very confused question. Prepositions do not affect the tense/aspect of a verb. "I have been on this project four years ago" is not a natural sentence. I don't see what the verb 'trip' has to do with this. Could you try to clarify your question?

Comment: @tunny : Thanks but you can check this out here http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37897/combine-two-sentence-into-one-sentence   please check steve's comment

Comment: It was pointed out in the thread you linked us to that you go 'on a trip'. That has nothing to do with whether or not the present perfect is used.

Comment: @tunny : steve leaved comments like this. None of the 3 "join project" sentences are correct. I joined this project 4 years ago. I have been on this project now for 4 years. It has been 4 years since I joined this project. I have been working on this project since 4 years ago. –  Wichita Steve 4 hours ago

Comment: @tunny: he written like this, I have been on this project now for 4 years. He used what 'have been on'. I just point out this sentence.

Comment: In this case, "have been on" means "a member of".

Comment: @Wichita Steve: Is that special case to use?  I have been asking about the general usage of the 'on' in have pp sentence.

Comment: @tunny  : can I use like this sentence "I have been (in/on/to) a car accident" instead of "I have been on this project now for 4 years" without start time? Also if you can please let me know each preposition usage in have been sentence structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of using 'on' after 'have been' is perfectly natural.

However the sentence you have provided is grammatically incorrect -

I have been on this project 4 years ago.  ('ago' is not used for the actions which are still continued in the present)

So first let's modify your sentence in the correct form.

1. I have been on this project for the past four years.

Examples

1. (Macmillan) The Vietnam War ended over 30 years ago.
2. (Macmillan) It was ages ago that I saw Mick.
3. (Cambridge) The dinosaurs died out 65 million years ago.
4. I had seen that movie a long time ago.
5. (Oxford) She was here just a minute ago.

**'Ago' by its definition relates only to the things that happened in the past. So you would hardly or almost never find or make a sentence with the word 'ago' in any form of present of future tense.**

Your example (I have been on this project 4 years ago.) is of the present tense.

In this example 'on' is short-formed for 'verb+ing' - Let's see how -

1. I have been working on this project for the past 4 years.
2. This project's been going on for the past 4 years.
3. How long have you been on this project? (Asking the question by omitting the word 'working' is informal and is a less professional way. But still it is correct sentence formation)

Comment: Did you mean that tunny's answer is wrong?

Comment: As I know my example is present perfect. Not just present. And join's time point is past not present. If I right, I can use 'ago' in my example sentence. Am I wrong?

Comment: Certainly your sentence is present perfect. And although you joined in the past 'you are still connected and involved with that project, aren't you'? (Refer to my explanation - 'ago' is not used for the actions which are still continued in the present) So you can't use 'ago' in this example or in any other sentence where any form of present tense is invovled (present simple, present continuous or present perfect tense)

Comment: and which of tunny's answer that you refer to here ? (Is it the first comment ?)

Comment: I mean here //tunny : steve leaved comments like this. None of the 3 "join project" sentences are correct. I joined this project 4 years ago. I have been on this project now for 4 years. It has been 4 years since I joined this project. I have been working on this project since 4 years ago. – Wichita Steve 4 hours ago –  user1917217 8 hours ago   delete

Comment: Although I joined the project but the project finished as soon. And although The project was finished but I am not quit the company.

Comment: No - I think first three sentences are correct. Except the second sentence could be modified as 'I have been on this project for 4 years now. The last sentence should be 'I have been working on this project since 4 years.'

Comment: If the project is finished then the sentence should be 'I had been on this project for 4 years.' Or 'I worked / had worked on that project 4 years ago.'

Comment: you might want to refer to the following link - http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/162244/can-i-use-the-present-perfect-tense-with-a-specific-time-expression

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18245/discussion-between-user1917217-and-leo).

Comment: sure we could do that